# .change() function breaking .resize() script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page containing a bunch of content blocks—`$('.asset)`—that link to downloadable content. There's a `<select>` element that triggers a script to show only the blocks with class names that correspond to the current `value` of the `<select>`.

```
$('select#academy').change(function() {
  var value =  this.value,
    $asset = $('.asset');
  
  $asset.hide().removeClass('is-showing');
  $('.asset.' + value).show().addClass('is-showing');
  if (value == 'all') {
    $asset.show().addClass('is-showing');
  }
});
```

Works beautifully. The blocks contain tiles that are sized to be square at all times with the following script:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var $assetTitle = $('.asset-title'),
    assetWidth  = $assetTitle.width();

  $assetTitle.css('height', assetWidth + 32);
}).resize();
```

Works fine and responsively in all browsers I've tested, and renders fine on page load on mobile devices.

### The Problem

I've found that on my iOS device, when I change the `value` of the `select`, once I start scrolling, the `.resize()` script seems to go out the window, and all of my `$('.asset-title')` elements lose their `height`.

This is a bug on a live project, so you can check it out (and see markup/inspect styles) here: [adaptiva.com/academy](http://adaptiva.com/academy)

### Solved

My script was calculating the width of the first `.asset` element, which was likely hidden on `.change()`. I altered my script to only target the visible `.asset` elements (with the class `is-showing`) and responsively calculate their heights accordingly.

Comment: Not sure since you did not posted your HTML... (So I can't recreate the issue) but on `resize`, if you try to get the `height` of an hidden element, it will be 0 (zero). That looks like to be be your issue... So on resize, I would loop through each `.asset` elements to get their display state. Then `.show()` them all just the time it takes to get measurements, and restore their display state.

Comment: try to debug which make the .asset-title hight 0

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette You were right — my script was calculating the `width` of the first `.asset` element, which was likely hidden on `.change()`. I altered my script to only target the visible `.asset` elements and responsively calculate their heights accordingly. Thanks for the tip!